# Send Treeview Selected Node value to textbox without postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, treeview

I've been working on this for quite a while and haven't found anything to solve my problem. When I select a node I want the value of that node to populate a textbox. I can get this to work using vb codebehind but it causes a postback and I don't want it to. I want to try to use javascript to do this instead but I'm not sure where call the function or how to set it up.

Here's the code for my treeview and the textbox I want to send it to:

> ```
> <asp:TextBox ID="tbSelectedOrg" runat="server" Enabled="false" asp:TextBox>
> ```

```
              <asp:TreeView 
                ID="tvOrganizationTree" 
                ExpandDepth="0"
                runat="server" 
                PopulateNodesFromClient = "true" 
                ShowLines="true" 
                ShowExpandCollapse="true"
                OnSelectedNodeChanged="tvOrganizationTree_SelectedNodeChanged"> // currently calls vb code causing postback
              </asp:TreeView>
```

Answer (score 1):

I created this example really quick. Give it a try.

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%= TreeView1.ClientID %> div a").click(function () {
            $("#txt").val(this.innerHTML);
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server">
    </asp:TreeView>
    <input type="text" id="txt" />
</asp:Content>
```

Good luck!

Comment: That comes very close to working, my only issue is that I can't open up different levels of the tree view now. When I click on the "+" button to view the child nodes it just populates my textbox with the code that created the "+" image and doesn't display the child nodes. If I click on the root node, that value populates the textbox correctly.

Comment: Working on a solution to this.

Comment: Sorry I was caught up doing something different at work. Check the code now, I just changed the jquery selector to target all of the link tags inside the divs inside the tree, which are the children nodes in your treeview. This will give you an idea of how it works in case you need to do some extra changes. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the code. It's getting closer to working. Now I can open the child nodes, but when I click on a node it does a post back. When the page reloads all of the child nodes I originally opened stay opened, but I can no longer open more. This second time when I click on a node it places the name (text) of it into the textbox, but when I click to open child nodes it doesn't open, it just takes the text that makes up the "+" button and puts that into the textbox.

Comment: I wonder if that has anything to do with me using node.PopulateOnDemand in the dynamic creation of my treeview. [Here's](http://aspalliance.com/732_Display_Hierarchical_Data_with_TreeView_in_ASPNET_20) the source I used to help me generate the treeview.

Comment: I found a way to see each item in my table. Each one has a similar id with a number attached to the end of it ("commonIdNameForNodes17"). Is there a way in jquery to perform this action on elements with id's that contain "commonIdNameForNodes".

Answer (score 0):

I would use JQuery to solve such a problem.

This code is not perfect but should give you an idea of where to look:

```
 $("#tvOrganizationTree .what-ever-class-aspnet-gives-the-nodes")
        .click(function() 
        { 
            $("#id-of-textbox").html(this.html());
        });
```

Comment: Why do you use `.html()` instead of `val()` to set the _value_ of the `TextBox`?

Comment: @David Perlman, How can I go about getting the class the asp.net gives the nodes?

Comment: @Jupaol thanks for the correction. The code sample was to show the basic idea not solve the problem.

Comment: Try using the dev tools on IE or FireBug on Firefox to inspect the Html output.

Comment: @David Perlman, I've tried using the dev tool in IE to see how to identify each node. My problem is that I start out with only one node showing because I use node.populate on demand for all of the child nodes. This means that when I inspect the source code there is only one row in the table (node in the treeview). If I expand that node the source code does not change at all. It only changes if I do a post back. I have to use node.populateOnDemand because it's a tree containing over 3700 nodes and it would require a lot of uneeded calls to the database.